# How to modify a variable/flag for all objects in the list without using for each loop or any loop in kotlin and get same list back after operation?

Tags: android, kotlin

Suppose that i have this kind of Model:

```
data class Account(var name:String, var isVisible:Boolean=false, var someId:Int, var type:Int)
```

Now suppose i have a list of accounts i.e. `var accountList = ArrayList<Account>()`

Also assume I have lot of account objects in accountList.

Now I have a requirement that I should make isVisible true for all of the objects for which type variable is 1 and sometimes I have to make isVisible true for all the objects that has type as 2.

Currently I am doing it using for each loop which makes code look very messy and big. (Since i have many such scenarios of making the isVisible true or false depending on values of different variables in Account object )
Is their an operator with some lambda expression or something to do so in kotlin ?

**P.S.
I do not want new list in return of the operator, I want to modify objects in existing list only using an operator. (for example filter operator returns a new list of filtered objects everytime we call it, which I dont want. I want to modify my list only using a short and crisp code or an operator)**

Comment: Can you show an example of how such operator should look like? Anyway, you always can create your own extension function

Comment: Hey @IR42 mate, yes i was thinking of the same to create my own extension function for the list. I am thinking to find some operator that maybe help me do something like this list.changeValues(type-> (type==1) isVisible=true) something like this. Which maybe will tell my list that for whoever has type ==1 make isVisible true for them. I am not sure in map or any other we can do such thing. If i am not able to find maybe i will have to create my own method.

Comment: what you described can be implemented with `filter {...}.forEach {...}`, but as you noted, `filter` creates a new collection. To avoid this, you can use [`Sequences`](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/sequences.html) ( `accountList.asSequence().filter {...}.forEach {...}` ), (or you can just use `forEach { if {...} }`. But it is still better to create a separate function if this code is often repeated

Comment: What is your concern regarding creating a new list with `filter()`? If your only concern is that you need to modify objects in the original list then... this is not a problem really. Just use `filter{}.forEach{}` and you will actually modify objects in the original list.

Comment: @broot suppose if i am using original list in recyclerview, I do not want to create new list everytime for each operation and give it to my adapter. The way i see it is:  its better to modify original list and call notifiyDataSetChanged on adapter. Also new list takes up its own memory in the heap right, now for each operation if i end up getting or creating new list then it may cause some issue in the future with memory. Please correct me if I am wrong or if theres a better approach. Also too many for each loops for each operation make code look very ugly. So just thought to ask here.

Comment: You don't need to provide a new list to an adapter. As I said, by using `filter{}.forEach{}` you modify objects in the original list as well, so this is really equivalent of looping over an original list. And regarding the memory, it shouldn't really be a problem as long as you don't create millions of such lists. Don't do premature optimizations :-)

Comment: okay broot, I understand, Thank you. But another part of my question is that.. is their more simpler way to do so without writing for each loop? Because the code looks very big when I am using forEach Loop  as there are many conditions and checks that I have written inside it. So if theres no other operator or something, ill continue using this way with filter and Sequences, as @IR42 and you suggested. I might write these stuffs in an extension function for my arraylist.

Comment: @broot .filter{].forEach{} will traverse through the newly created list by .filter right? how will it modify my original list. Or do you mean to say using it with sequence as IR42 suggested ?

Comment: `filter()` creates a shallow copy, meaning that it creates a new list of exactly the same objects as in original list. You can't use this new list to anyhow add or remove items to/from the original list, but any modifications to objects will be visible in original list, because both lists share same items. It wouldn't work for lists of primitives though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `onEach` extension for this:

```
accountList.onEach { it.isVisible = true }
```